# Failed to start Neo4j service

Tags: service, neo4j

I am using neo4j enterprise 3.0.3 version for windows. Following the operations manual 3.0, I have installed the neo4j service with `bin\neo4j install-service`. But I can't start it with `bin\neo4j start`. It said

> Invoke-Neo4j : Failed to start service 'Neo4j Graph Database - neo4j (neo4j)'.

And I can't start the neo4j service in windows serice either. Maybe anyone have encountered this case before?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem: I am using neo4j community 3.1.2 for windows and installed the service with the neo4j.bat file without any problems.Then i wanted to start the service with neo4j.bat and got the same error as you

I found a solution that worked for me. My neo4j files were in a folder, where the path to the folder contained spaces (C:\Program Files\Neo4j) Then i moved the folder one level up (C:\Neo4j). 
After that i could start the service without problems.

Maybe this solution helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
neo4j console
```

Posting for latest versions > 4.x 
I had the same issue using neo4j start, Neo4j console is the right command I was looking for. It is a web-based graph that acts as an interactive tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I am running neo4j on windows and in my case the crux of the issue was that there was an incompatibility between the installed versions of Java (32-bit) v/s OS version. The biggest clue that led me to this is the following set of lines in neo4j-service.2018-08-03 log file

[2018-08-03 14:55:42] [info]  [ 1432] Starting service...
[2018-08-03 14:55:42] [error] [ 1432] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[2018-08-03 14:55:42] [error] [ 1432] Failed creating java C:\JavaNew\bin\server\jvm.dll
[2018-08-03 14:55:42] [error] [ 1432] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[2018-08-03 14:55:42] [error] [ 1432] ServiceStart returned 1

There are a fair number of potential issues, and I have made an attempt to compile all the issues with this,

1. Windows services cannot deal with service names in folders that have spaces; especially if there is another folder with the same name as the one with spaces.
   For example - C:\Program Files... will have issues if C:\Program\Something...

   To work around this, I put Neo4j in root folder c:\Neo4j
2. Get-Java.ps1 (under  ..\bin\Neo4j-Management folder)looks in the path variable for 'JAVA_HOME' (usually found in *nix environments). If it does not find it here, it keeps looking in registry, and finally throws up its hand!

   To deal with this, I simply put in a path variable. For a good measure, I uninstalled Java and re-installed Java in the root folder under C:\JavaNew

   In retrospect, this step is probably not on part of the problem, and hence can be ignored. But I am leaving it here for completeness sake.
3. Invoke-Neo4j.ps1 (also under ..\bin\Neo4j-Management folder) has code that determines if the OS is 32-bit (or 64-bit). Based on this it determines if it should run prunsrv-i386.exe (32-bit) or prunsrv-amd64.exe (64-bit).

   This has to match the Java version installed.

   Upon running java -XshowSettings:all, and inspecting the sun.arch.data.model value (32, in my case), I realized that my OS is 64 bit and the Java version is 32-bit.

   To deal with this, I put in code (very klugey!). I am sure there are much better ways to get to the same outcome, but this is what I used.

   switch ( (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Processor | Select-Object -First 1).Addresswidth ) {
     32 { $PrunSrvName = 'prunsrv-i386.exe' }  # 4 Bytes = 32bit
     #64 { $PrunSrvName = 'prunsrv-amd64.exe' } # 8 Bytes = 64bit   COMMENTED as a workaround!!!
     64 { $PrunSrvName = 'prunsrv-i386.exe' } # 8 Bytes = 64bit
4. Now, uninstall the neo4j service, install it, and start the service.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem , after the neo4j worked for few weeks it stoop working (without any change that i made)
i have set java_home uninstall and install and now it works

neo4j-enterprise-3.3.4

Answer (score 0):

I was also having weired issue as there was no error but neo4J service did not start.

```
[xx@ss1 bin]$ ./neo4j console
[xx@ss1 bin]$ .
```

The problem was with the permission on Java directory and I tried

```
chmod -R 777 jdk_directory
```

and problem got solved.

#neo4j #neo4jnotstarting